# Mongo aggregation: removing empty documents and returning distinct results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am querying a fairly large collection (20 million records+). I need to pull out only specific field values, and I would also like to eliminate empty documents from the results (documents that don't have any relevant values) and also group by/find some other way to only return unique document objects, to lessen the amount of records returned.

Let's say the collection data looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d81f1f7453b000734c603"), 
    "name" : "question_group",
    "questions" : [
        {
            "question_other_field": "testing"
        }
        {
            "question_type" : "newbie", 
            "question_value" : "how to query data"
        }, 
        {
            "question_type" : "newbie", 
            "question_value" : "how to query data",
            "question_metadata" : {
                "question_subject_name" : "Mongo"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "question_type" : "newbie", 
            "question_value" : "how to query data",
            "question_other_field": "testing"
            "question_metadata" : {
                "question_subject_name" : "Mongo"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "question_type" : "expert", 
            "question_value" : "how not to query data", 
            "question_timestamp" : 1556854333, 
            "question_metadata" : {
                "question_subject_name" : "Mongo", 
                "question_answer_id" : "19247100",
                "question_answer_events" : {
                      "attitude" : "helpful",
                      "result" : "success"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For some records, the questions array is empty, and when it isn't, sometimes certain inner fields and objects exist, sometimes they don't. And I want to query the whole collection and export just the values for these fields:

```
questions.question_type
questions.question_value
questions.question_metadata.question_subject_name
questions.question_metadata.question_answer_events.attitude
questions.question_metadata.question_answer_events.result
```

If any of those fields are blank or non-existent, that's ok. But if all of the fields are empty however, I want to omit that row; I don't want a document returned with zero fields. And lastly, again because it's a large collection, I want to return distinct values, so that if two or more resulting documents have the exact same five values for all of the above five fields, I want them grouped into one row. (I don't really need a count of how many in each group, though maybe that would be nice in addition.)

Here's what I would ideally expect to get back in an export, based on the small sample of example data I gave above. There are three results; the first record above is not in the results because it contains none of the fields I'm looking up, and the third and fourth are combined into one row because while they are different, the difference is not in one of the query fields.

```
question_type: "newbie"
question_value: "how to query data"
question_subject_name: 
attitude: 
result:

question_type: "newbie"
question_value: "how to query data"
question_subject_name: "Mongo"
attitude: 
result:

question_type: "expert"
question_value: "how not to query data"
question_subject_name: "Mongo"
attitude: helpful 
result: success
```

I'm totally new to Mongo and querying and this is the best I've come up with so far:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        questions: {
            $ne: []
        }
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$questions"
},
{
    $project: { 
        "_id": 0,
        question_type: "$questions.question_type",
        question_value: "$questions.question_value",
        question_subject_name: "$questions.question_metadata.question_subject_name",
        question_answer_events: "$questions.question_metadata.question_answer_events"
    } 
},
{
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        question_type: "$question_type",
        question_value: "$question_value",
        question_subject_name: "$question_subject_name",
        attitude: "$question_answer_events.attitude",
        result: "$question_answer_events.result",
    }
}
])
```

The $match and $unwind may be redundant, if $unwind is already eliminating rows without a questions array, but I'm not sure. Further, with this query I get non-distinct results (because I don't know how) and also I get some rows returning that have zero fields, implying (likely correctly) that the original row had a questions array but an entirely different set of fields.

Any help is much appreciated, for this former lurker!

Comment: **I get non-distinct results** you unwind so it will flat the array. Can you show us your expected result?

Comment: Thanks. I will edit my question to clarify that. Comment editing is not ideal to do so.